# How to scrape data from Google sheets to present it on webpage by using Gscript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to use Dynamic HTML table in Googleapps script to fetch data from Google sheets. But not able to implement it successfully.

Comment: Please share some code or what you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ not scrap

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Apps Script?

You can use the [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) to interact with the spreadsheet.

---

**Further reading:**

[Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)